# Border-radius with Knockout drop-down list issue

Tags: css, knockout.js, drop-down-menu

Trying to add border-radius to a drop-down Knockout list, but only 'submit' will take it. Other styles are applied to all. Have also tried -moz and -webkit, and have looked at style and css bindings, but not sure how to properly apply. Have also tried just a css style on 'select', which applies all styles but the border-radius.

```
<select data-bind="options: searchParameters, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select a Search', value: searchCanlii, css: { drop: on }" ></select>
<select data-bind="options: citedNode, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select a Node', value: nodeID, css: { drop: on }" ></select>
<button data-bind='click: submit, css: { drop: on }'  >submit</button>


.drop {
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(107, 118, 108, 0.05);
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    color: rgba(1, 73, 111, .7);
    font-family: 'Ovo', serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;   
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 0 rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yoreto/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

> css: { drop: on }

from [Ivaylo Gerchev's article on KnockoutJS](http://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-to-knockoutjs-part-2/)

Comment: Solved using `appearance:none;` in styles (sourced from [http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3)

Comment: you ought to post that comment (in fleshed out form) as the answer. You'd gain oodles of fame and glory, and maybe an upvote or three ;)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't apply border radius to `<select>` elements.**

The binding is correct which is why all the other css properties are working.

Also that jsbin you posted is reporting 10 errors, errors can cause bindings to fail so be careful in the future when trying to solve problems, first make sure there's no errors.

Comment: Actually i eat my words, i increased the border radius and it seems to be applying the radius for me, I am using chrome, also tried in IE11 with success.

Comment: FF works, but Chrome seems to continue to ignore. How are you using Chrome?

Comment: I looked at [link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3) which uses appearance: none; which I had come across and tried, but adding this works in the Chrome viewer for Netbeans8: `-webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none; `

Comment: My chrome version is: Version 35.0.1916.114 m